# How do SO answerers convert a questioner's dataframe output into a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Up till now, I have mainly asked questions so I didn't realize, but I was wondering what is the fastest to way to take data like this that is copied from another SO's post/question and convert it to a dataframe that I can play with and test out the given solutions:

```
1       2           time    4
13.45   9/29/2016   6:00    98765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:05    76548
13.45   9/29/2016   6:07    98764
13.45   9/29/2016   6:21    98766
13.45   9/29/2016   6:20    96765
12.56   9/29/2016   6:06    76553
```

Do you guys copy and past it and then manually convert it to a dictionary form?
I think I remember there being an option where I can convert my clipboard into a dataframe. Is that the method most answerers use?

Do answerers prefer a certain format from questioners? i.e. Question's dataframe is in dictionary form, so that you can just reproduce the dataframe by copying and pasting it into Python?

Comment: read about `pd.read_clipboard()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First copy `DataFrame` from question and then use [`read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html):

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print (df)

       1          2  time      4
0  13.45  9/29/2016  6:00  98765
1  12.56  9/29/2016  6:05  76548
2  13.45  9/29/2016  6:07  98764
3  13.45  9/29/2016  6:21  98766
4  13.45  9/29/2016  6:20  96765
5  12.56  9/29/2016  6:06  76553
```